# MySQLi result to array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Currently my code outputs 1 array, it doesn't display all. I understand that I need a while or foreach loop to display the rest.

Here is my current code:

```
/**
 * Get work orders via email and password and institution id
 */
public function getWorkOrdersByInstitution($email, $password, $institution_id) {

    $work_order_stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM project WHERE institution_id = ?");

    $work_order_stmt->bind_param("s", $institution_id);

    if ($work_order_stmt->execute()) {
        $workorder = $work_order_stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $work_order_stmt->close();

       return $workorder;

    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I want it to return the array. Currently this is what is returned (note: I am using json_encode when displaying the array):

```
{
    "project_id": 1,
    "date": "Undefined",
    "project_code": "ea60f6190c",
    "title": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "demo_url": null,
    "project_category_id": null,
    "client_id": null,
    "company_id": null,
    "staffs": "4,5,",
    "budget": 0,
    "timer_status": 0,
    "timer_starting_timestamp": null,
    "total_time_spent": 0,
    "progress_status": null,
    "timestamp_start": "1516874400",
    "timestamp_end": "1516878000",
    "project_status": 1,
    "project_note": null,
    "institution_id": 12,
    "project_state": 2,
    "strata_manager": 6,
    "site_contact": 7,
    "place_of_service": 18
}
```

So ultimately, I want all the rows to be stored in 1 array which I can return and use on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use a loop to get all your results :

```
if ($work_order_stmt->execute()) {
    $result = $work_order_stmt->get_result() ;

    $workorders = [] ;
    while ($workorder = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $workorders[] = $workorder ;
    }
    $work_order_stmt->close();

   return $workorders;
}
else { .. }
```

Or you could use [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get all data :

```
$workorders = $result->fetch_all();
```